# Symfony 3 - static CollectionType children not showing up

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I am working on a form in Symfony 3.1.3 and want to add a dynamic amount of checkboxes using `CollectionType`. In the `buildForm`-method of my `Type`-class I am using this code to add the Checkboxes:

```
    $builder->add('levels', CollectionType::class, array(
        'entry_type' => CheckboxType::class,
        'mapped' => false,
    ));

    foreach($levels as $level) {
        $name = 'level_cb_'.$level['name'];
        $builder->get('levels')->add($name, CheckboxType::class, array(
            'label' => $level['name'],
            'required' => false,
            'mapped' => false,
        ));
    }
```

If I call `var_dump($builder->get('levels'));` immediately afterwards the checkboxes show up in the `children` and `unresolvedChildren` properties of the `CollectionType`. Later I call `{{ dump(form.levels) }}` in the associated template and it shows me that the `children` property is empty.

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems that the children of the collection get cleared somewhere between being added in my custom Type and the form being made available in the Controller.

I put the code to add the checkboxes into the controller and suddenly everything worked as expected. Maybe someone knows the reason behind that.

So in my SpecialType.php I just have:

```
    $builder->add('levels', CollectionType::class, array(
        'entry_type' => CheckboxType::class,
        'required' => false,
        'mapped' => false,
    ));
```

And in my SpecialFormController.php I have:

```
    $form = $this->createForm(SpecialType::class, $entity);
    foreach($levels as $level) {
        $name = 'level_cb_'.$level['name'];
        $form->get('levels')->add($name, CheckboxType::class, array(
            'label' => $level['name'],
            'required' => false,
            'mapped' => false,
        ));
    }
```